# Running multiple Node.js or Python scripts

Tags: python, node.js, discord, autostart

I was wandering if there was a way I could easily use Windows Task Scheduler in order to run multiple scripts at the same time. I am wanting to host multiple discord bots on a spare PC that would each have their own bot key for different discord servers; my current understanding is that you cannot easily run multiple node.js bots like this (currently I have 1 in the scheduler and the other I have to run manually) but I was wandering if this is something that can be done in Python or if I can make it happen with node.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really into Python, don't fall for the name hehe

Anyway, logically speaking this is a threading problem, did you try enabling multiple threading in the program you are using? or dynamically allow the program/code to create multiple threads to handle multiple tasks related to the Node.js file you are using!?

Best Regards

Comment: I have no idea what any of this means, currently I have 2 separate (I think they are) bat files that run "node main.js /k"

Comment: hello again, what I meat was checking in your program's setting if it has an option for multi-threading. enable that if the option is there. otherwise, I am clueless. told you not a python guy, however, c# is my thing :) Best regards